# How to get the discount amount code of voucher applied in prestashop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop-1.6

I am attaching the below snapshots of prestashop shopping cart So how I will get the code of discount amount from the voucher redeemed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N20lU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vSd0.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getCartRules()` function to fetch all the cart rules applied on any cart. This function is defined in the Cart.php class file.

You can use the following code to fetch all the coupon details on current cart:

```
$this->context->cart->getCartRules();
```

and you can use below code to know if the customer is using the voucher for the first time.

```
if ($context->cart->id_customer) {
        $quantityUsed = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_cart_rule od ON o.id_order = od.id_order
        WHERE o.id_customer = '.$context->cart->id_customer.'
        AND od.id_cart_rule = '.(int)$this->id.'
        AND '.(int)Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR').' != o.current_state
        ');
        if ($quantityUsed == 0) {
          // Customer is using the coupon for first time.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok It worked and how to get to know that particular customer has used the voucher for the first time

Comment: We have just updated our answer with the code to know if a customer is using the voucher for the first time.

Comment: Ok First I will create a voucher which gives 10% discount on the final amount of the product We are giving 5000 credit cash for each registered customer in our website...The customer can use the voucher until 5000 rupees got over.when the order got placed using the above mentioned voucher I want to display the discount amount deducted from the 5000 example for first order discount is 500(5000-500=4500 I should get ) for the first time of the voucher used
For the second order using the same voucher discount suppose the discount amount is 400 amount should be (4500-400=4100)