# Fetch discounts list using PHP in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, module, cart, prestashop-1.7, discount

The site I'm working on requires me to fetch the available discount for a product and let the customer select the discount from the available options. I tried the below code from [How to get the discount amount code of voucher applied in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763488/how-to-get-the-discount-amount-code-of-voucher-applied-in-prestashop) to fetch the discounts but I'm getting an empty array.

Below being the code on Prestashop controller for fetching discounts.

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$result = $context->cart->getCartRules(10);
$response = array('status' => true, "message" => $module->l('It works !'), 'result' => $result);
```

I'm getting an empty array in the result.

[image]

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it without the ajax call. 
What must be done is just create a discount for a product in the Prestashop admin backend. And then display the discounts in the front end template files using the cart class.

```
{foreach from=$cart.discounts item=discount}
  <li class="cart-summary-line">
    <input type="radio" name="trade-in-discount" value="{$discount.code}"><span class="label">{$discount.name}</span>
  </li>
{/foreach}
```